# how to set vertical line to 100% in detaiils section?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

i need to create a report like this.. i am using pentaho report

[image]

i need to create a vertical line like that...

i tried to use rectangle but still have the same result.

so i have a fix details's height.

i tried to search some documentation but still have no idea to create like this..

from this case i just have 1 row in details, but i must set a height to 100% instead depend on much row in details.

[image]

or see this [PDF](http://www.4shared.com/web/preview/pdf/w7A8cniIba?), 
http://www.4shared.com/web/preview/pdf/w7A8cniIba?
the vertical line on detail's section not 100% to bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no option to set a height to 100%. But there is a solution, In **Details section**, you can increase the height of  **Details section** and then  drag   vertical line to the end of the **Details section**. Execute and see still if there is a gap between Details section and **Report Footer** section again increase the **Details section** up to vertical line will reach to **Report Footer** section

Comment: if i set a height's size to details section then every row in details section will have that height's size?

Comment: Here you are talking about more than one row in details section?

Comment: yess... see this link http://www.4shared.com/web/preview/pdf/w7A8cniIba

Comment: If it's one row in details section my solution should work otherwise, you have to write a formula for the height of the vertical line.

Comment: i think one solution, i must set a fix loop on detail's section, so every time i call that report, it always have that fixed rows